# Mistake in HW question about 4-color theorem?

Tags: graph-theory, proof-verification, coloring

> Let there be a map created by a finite number of lines in the plane (countries are connected domains in the map). Prove you can color the countries in **two** colors such that neighboring countries always have different colors.

I think the bold 'two' is a mistake - just take a collection of countries such that each one neighbors the other two. I think the intention was 'four'.

In that case, my idea is to pass to "the" dual graph and apply the four color theorem. However, I remember hearing something about dual graphs generally not being unique (i.e can be non-isomorphic). I think I'm supposed to explain why dual graphs are unique in this case, but I don't know how...

Comment: lines in this case do indeed mean infinite straight non curved lines. A collection of countries probably doesn't have lines as borders.  Intuitively I think this is probably true and I think it can be argued by induction. A plane with n-1 lines requires two colors.  A third color cuts plane in right.  Reverse all the colors of the left half plane and you are just fine.  Fails if the lines aren't straight or infinite.

Comment: @fleablood yeah, that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: "lines" can be ambiguous considering classically the mean any curve and in the four color problem (which this *sounds* like it is stating) don't use lines or areas but graphs, it's understandable it wasn't clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think **two** is correct and by lines you mean non-ending lines (no arcs/line segments or no start/end points) with transversal intersections (hence every line divides your plane in (at least) two planes, each to one side of the line).

**Hint**: Give every line an orientation and consider the colors $-1$ and $1$. For a country, take as color$=(-1)^k$ where $k$ denotes the number of lines, this domain lays left to the line.

Comment: In particular, the lines extend infinitely.

Comment: @JoshB. not necessarily, you can have also a loop (but for straight lines it is way easier to see). Important is, they don't have start/end points and only intersect transversal.

Comment: Fair enough. My point was that the OP may be confused by considering line segments.

Comment: So we can't have a point which is a "triple intersection? Intersections must be even?

Comment: Right, since the line doesn't stop.

Comment: @JoshB. Considered your point and changed to non-ending lines